# React Native Remove Autofill Space with State set Input

Tags: react-native, trim, use-state

I'm running into the issue with my login screen where people autofill in their emails so it leaves a space at the end of the screen. I want to clear that when they move to add their password so was thinking of doing a **onBlur** that could probably use a .trim() or .replace() but how do I use that with my setEmail useState?

Screen blow:

```
const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const LogInUser = async() => {
        if(email && password) {
            try {
                await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                setEmail('')
                setPassword('')
                setError('')
                navigation.replace('Home')
                console.log('User Logged In = ');
            } catch (err){
                setError('Email or Password is wrong!');
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }

    return (
    <DismissKeyboard>     
        <View style={styles.screenStyle}>
        <View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill }}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/images/AccountBG.png')} style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null}} />
            </View>               
            <StatusBar hidden={true} />
            <View style={styles.loginBox}>
                <Text style={[styles.whiteText, styles.headTextH1, styles.headingBufferBottom]}>Welcome</Text>
                <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{error}</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyles}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000"
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={setEmail}
                    onBlur={cleanEmail}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyles}
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder="Password"
                    placeholderTextColor="#000"
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                />
                <OGButton title="Login" onPress={()=> LogInUser()} />
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.registerBox, styles.whiteText]}>
                <Text style={styles.whiteText}>Don't have an account? | </Text>
                <Text style={[styles.underlineText, styles.whiteText]} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')} >Register Here</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </DismissKeyboard>        
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim the values and setEmail and whatever checks needed in onChangeText

```
 onChangeText={(val) => {
  // have other checks if needed here
 setEmail(val.trim())
  }
 }
```